# how to gnuboard5 + laravel5

Tags: php, laravel, vendor

I like Gnuboard 5.3.
I want to extend my Gnuboard using Laravel.
How do you combine the current version of Gnuboard 5.3 with Laravel?

I'd like to know how to add it to the vendor of Laravel.

Thank you!

Comment: What is Gnuboard, can you link to this library/framework/thing?

Comment: Gnuboard 5.3 is a website created by SIR(https://sir.kr)
PHP source made in Korea.
distributed in tar.gz form
BBS management and website production are easy.
The shopping mall combined with
There is YoungCart5.
Recently, Gnuboard 5.3 appeared as a multilingual version.
https://gnuboard.com

In Korea, it is widely used in various web agent
You don't have a market as big as Wordpress,
It's growing.